# Linksys E2500 V3 randomly drops connection

Tags: wireless-networking, router, dd-wrt

I have two units of Linksys E2500 V3 that I use as access points, they are both connected by LAN to a Linksys E1200 that is my gateway. These two E2500 would randomly have problems. They would be working just fine for many weeks even months, then one day they would each have connectivity problems for the whole day. Among others:

- Lose connection to gateway. I would just suddenly not be able to get an IP address via wifi. When this happens I would unplug for 10-30 secs and plug back in. Sometimes this works, sometimes it would lose connection again within minutes.
- Wifi entirely shuts down. Won't be able to connect via wifi at all and keeps asking me to enter password as if I entered the wrong one, while in fact I did not change any passwords nor settings on my device. I would unplug and plug back in and that usually fixes it... for a while... Could be working again for a day or a month. Completely random.

Strangely this is happening to both units, each of which were bought at very different times years apart. I have tried running stock firmware, DD-WRT, and currently running Advanced Tomato on each of them, but still running into this problem. It's very disappointing. The E1200 gateway that is cheaper just runs all day long with no problems at all.

I also have Buffalo AirStations running side by side to these E2500s. The difference is the AirStations have VPNs on them while the E2500s is just a standard internet connection. The AirStations very rarely have problems, and I made sure every access point is running on a different channel. I also made sure if two access points are physically very close to each other the gap between their respective channels is higher than 1.

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Have you pulled the logs and seen what they show? dmesg or anything? Also, your channel separation isn't enough, they should be using channels 1, 6, 11 wherever overlapping may occur or you will get interference.

Comment: Thanks @acejavelin for your comment. Which logs should I pull? I took a look at them and they make no sense to me. What is dmesg? By overlapping do you mean physically overlapping signals or do you mean APs that have the same name?

Comment: dmesg is driver messages, to see if the wifi drivers is error out, or look at the kernel messages (/var/logs). APs which cover the same physical area should have unique channel separation, +/- 3 channel minimum, and should be a minimum 6 feet apart.